# Write to variable then to file or directly to file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code :

```
foo = json.loads(get_foo())

foo_file = ''
for f in foo['datas']:
    foo_file += f['bar'] + ' ' + f['barfoo'] + '\n'

with open(output, 'w') as output:
    output.write(foo_file)
```

Is it the correct way to do it, or should I directly write to file like this:

```
foo = json.loads(get_foo())

with open(output, 'w') as output:
    for f in foo['datas']:
        output.write(f['bar'] + ' ' + f['barfoo'] + '\n')
```

There is one variable less used, but the file is open for much more time. Is there is a lot of datas, isn't it bad for performances to write directly to the file?

Comment: It depends.. If you need some processing on data then that extra variable need to come into picture. else use it directly

Comment: Try the first option with a huge input and you'll find out why it's better to not try to fit everything in memory <g>. Might not be such of an issue in your case (json contents are _usually_ not that huge) if you only have one process/thread running that code but well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you write to a file directly (in code), the system will not immediately write to the file: it will use the operating system's (OS) policies regarding *buffering*: internally it is first stored in memory and only when the amount of content to be written exceeds a certain threshold, it is written to the file.

When using [`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) you can also specify the `buffering`.

But to come back to your question: I think the performance difference won't be that huge and furthermore it is not always possible to store all content in a variable first: say you want to write a `1 TiB` file, there is no way you can store the content fully in memory.

Finally note that you better use `.join` and string formatting to improve efficiency of string construction. This:

```
foo_file = ''
for f in foo['datas']:
    foo_file += f['bar'] + ' ' + f['barfoo'] + '\n'
```

can be replaced by:

```
foo_file = ''.join('%s %s\n'%(f['bar'],f['barfoo']) for f in foo['datas'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `writelines` here, python could choose the optimal way itself.

```
foo = json.loads(get_foo())

with open(output, 'w') as output:
    output.writelines(
        '{} {}\n'.format(f['bar'],f['barfoo'])
        for f in foo['datas']
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes much difference presuming that your f() is relatively quick. Either is fine. It may depend what you need it for, if you need to get at the data later on then option 1 is better otherwise option 2 is a little neater.

Comment: `f` is probably a dictionary, not a function. Furthermore I think the OP is more concerned about I/O overhead than CPU overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Performance should roughly be the same as writing to the file is buffered.

You could also do it like this:

```
foo = json.loads(get_foo())

with open(output, 'w') as output:
    for f in foo['datas']:
        output.write(f['bar'] + ' ' + f['barfoo'] + '\n')
```